# how to run a python script automatically after startx on raspberrypi

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, raspberry-pi, startup

I want to run a python script on raspberry pi when it is turned on. how can i do this? my script contains "Webkit" and 
"Gtk" modules. I've tried many methods but still not working. the code works perfectly through the python IDEL

Comment: editing rc local file by adding the location to it

Answer (score 1):

If you run a DE, then use the DE's session manager.

If you want to run *only* your application in fullscreen mode use the `~/.xinitrc` to lauch it.